java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization for class org.slf4j.helpers.BasicMarkerFactory
I am getting this error while deploying a spring application xapp WAR in JBOSS EAP 8 server. after migrating application from jboss eap7 to jboss eap 8, jdk 11 to 17 and spring 5 to spring 6.
I am using versions: JDK 17, spring framework 6.1.9, SLF4J 2.0.7.redhat-00002.
slf4j:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.redhat-00002</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

esapi:
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5.0</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>

below is the error:
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization for class org.slf4j.helpers.BasicMarkerFactory: when selecting method 'org.slf4j.Marker org.slf4j.IMarkerFactory.getDetachedMarker(java.lang.String)' the class loader 'org.slf4j@2.0.7.redhat-00002' @284707c5 for super interface org.slf4j.IMarkerFactory, and the class loader 'deployment.xapp-war.war' @29d09060 of the selected method's class, org.slf4j.helpers.BasicMarkerFactory have different Class objects for the type org.slf4j.Marker used in the signature (org.slf4j.IMarkerFactory is in unnamed module of loader 'org.slf4j@2.0.7.redhat-00002' @284707c5, parent loader 'app'; org.slf4j.helpers.BasicMarkerFactory is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.xapp-war.war' @29d09060, parent loader 'app')
        at deployment.xapp-war.war//org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogBridgeImpl.<clinit>(Slf4JLogBridgeImpl.java:35)
        at deployment.xapp-war.war//org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory.<clinit>(Slf4JLogFactory.java:96)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
        at deployment.xapp-war.war//org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.loadClassByStringName(ObjFactory.java:158)
        at deployment.xapp-war.war//org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:81)
        at deployment.xapp-war.war//org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.logFactory(ESAPI.java:139)
        at deployment.xapp-war.war//org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.getLogger(ESAPI.java:147)
        at deployment.xapp-war.war//com.cigna.ccmi.utils.SecureLogger.getLogger(SecureLogger.java:23)
        at deployment.xapp-war.war//com.cigna.ccmi.exception.mvc.CalcResponseExceptionHandler.<clinit>(CalcResponseExceptionHandler.java:29)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at deployment.xapp-war.war//org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:195)
        at deployment.xapp-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:88)
        at deployment.xapp-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1313)
        ... 33 more

below are the esapi configs
ESAPI.printProperties=true
Encryptor.CipherTransformation=AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
ESAPI.Encoder=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder
ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory
Logger.LogApplicationName=true
single-server environments.
Logger.LogServerIP=true
Logger.ApplicationName=xapp
Logger.LogEncodingRequired=false
Logger.UserInfo=false
Logger.ClientInfo=false
Logger.LogPrefix=false

can anyone help me resolve this error?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Try using ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory instead. It would likely perform better since it will end up being logged through the JBoss Log Manager anyway.
